# isalpha() giving an assertion

Tags: c, non-ascii-characters

I have a C code in which I am using standard library function isalpha() in ctype.h, This is on Visual Studio 2010-Windows.
In below code, if char c is '£', the isalpha call returns an assertion as shown in the snapshot below:

[image]

```
char c='£';

if(isalpha(c))
{
    printf ("character %c is alphabetic\n",c);

}
else
{
    printf ("character %c is NOT alphabetic\n",c);
}
```

I can see that this might be because 8 bit ASCII does not have this character.

So how do I handle such Non-ASCII characters outside of ASCII table?

What I want to do is if any non-alphabetic character is found(even if it includes  such character not in 8-bit ASCII table) i want to be able to neglect it.

Comment: Note that `'£'` is not an ASCII character. You're mixing contexts: the result can be surprising.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may want to cast the value sent to `isalpha` (and the other functions declared in `<ctype.h>`) to `unsigned char`

```
isalpha((unsigned char)value)
```

It's one of the (not so) few occasions where a cast is appropriate in C.

---

Edited to add an explanation.

According to [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), emphasis is mine

> 7.4
>
> 1 The header `<ctype.h>` declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping
>   characters. In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be
>   representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. **If the
>   argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.**

The cast to `unsigned char` ensures calling `isalpha()` does not invoke Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: thanks. char c; c='£'; isalpha((unsigned char)(c)); does work. No assertion and isalpha now returns '£' as NOT alphabetic.

Comment: @Alnitak: hehehe I didn't really explain anything ... post edited

Answer (score 8):

You must pass an `int` to `isalpha()`, not a `char`.  Note the standard prototype for this function:

```
int isalpha(int c);
```

Passing an 8-bit signed character will cause the value to be converted into a negative integer, resulting in an illegal negative offset into the internal arrays typically used by `isxxxx()`.

However you must ensure that your `char` is treated as `unsigned` when casting - you can't simply cast it directly to an `int`, because if it's an 8-bit character the resulting `int` would still be negative.

The typical way to ensure this works is to cast it to an `unsigned char`, and then rely on implicit type conversion to convert that into an `int`.

e.g.

```
char c = '£';
int a = isalpha((unsigned char) c);
```

Comment: I don't think so. Even when I tried - int c; c='£'; and passed it to isalpha(c), it asserts.

Comment: @goldenmean if your default chars are signed that'll still pass a negative integer.  What happens if you try `int c = (unsigned char)'£'` ?

Comment: As pmg answered above, char c; c='£'; isalpha((unsigned char)(c)); does work. No assertion and isalpha now returns '£' as NOT alphabetic.

Comment: @goldenmean yes, that's exactly what I was saying.

Comment: Thank you. +1 for explanation

Answer (score 2):

You may be compiling using wchar (UNICODE) as character type, in that case the isalpha method to use is iswalpha

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt82b8z8.aspx

Comment: K Thanks. Now used if(iswalpha(c)) ,it does not assert but now it passes '£' as a alphabetic character, when i want only letters([a..z]) to be deduced as alphabetic chars.

Comment: @Anders - now, unless goldenmean changes his char to wchar_t, he is mixing char and Unicode, which isn't right surely.