# Why isn't isalpha working?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm working with C and I need to check that the user inputed second command line argument argv[1] is made up of only alphabetical charchaters and if not, to do what is inside the else loop. I used the is alpha function but when i compile and run the program no matter what my second command line argument is (alphabetical or otherwise), its always executing the "else loop". How do i fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
  int a  = argc;    

  if (a != 2)
  {
    return 1;    
  }

  string b = argv [1]; 
  int c = strlen(b);
  string m;

  for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
  {
    if (isalpha(b[c]))
    { 
      m = GetString();    
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Please provide a valid keyword\n");
      return 1;
    }         
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `string` in the C world - Surely not C++

Comment: In the world of CS50, the `<cs50.h>` header contains `typedef char *string;` — a design that is questionable, but that's the way the course defines it.

Answer (score 10):

Try replacing

```
if (isalpha(b[c]))
```

with

```
if (isalpha(b[i]))
```

Currently you are checking the element at the index which is the result of `strlen(b)` at every iteration of your loop. Because array indices are zero based in C `b[strlen(b)]` is referencing `'\0'`, the null terminator.

In reference to the Keith Thompson comment below and the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693654/isalpha-giving-an-assertion) you should actually be casting the value passed to `isalpha` to an `unsigned char` to ensure that undefined behaviour is not invoked.

Thus you should change your code to

```
if (isalpha((unsigned char)b[i]))
```

to ensure there is no UB

Comment: `isalpha()` doesn't simply take a `char` argument. It takes an `int` argument whose value is converted from `unsigned char`. If plain `char` is signed (as it commonly is), then `isalpha(c)` has undefined behavior if `c < 0` (and `c != EOF`). Change `isalpha(b[i])` to `isalpha((unsigned char)b[i])`. (This is almost certainly not the cause of the OP's problem.)

Comment: Thanks, that helped :)

Comment: No you haven't. It should be `isalpha((unsigned char)b[i])`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isalpha(b[i])` instead of `isalpha(b[c])`
like this:

```
if (isalpha(b[i]))
{ 
  m = GetString();    
}
```