# C Program to count number of alphabets in a word giving error

Tags: c, character, getchar, isalpha

Following is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int alpha = 0, input;

    while((input = getchar() != EOF))
    {
        if(isalpha(input))
            alpha++;
    }

    printf("Num of alpha is %d", alpha);
    return(0);
}
```

I'm getting error as

> isalpha was not declared in this scope

when compiled on DevC++ compiler.

Comment: Please try to find some documentation about the `isalpha` function. It will tell you that you need to `#include` a specific header file.

Comment: The parameter to `isalpha()` is supposed to be cast to `unsigned char` prior to calling the function (`isalpha( (unsigned char)input )`). Not doing so can get you in trouble on some machines where `char` is signed.

Comment: @DevSolar Is that cast really necessary?

Comment: @klutt Indeed I was mistaking this for a different usecase, when the argument is `char` or `signed char`. No, it is nit strictly necessaty here. But it is a good habit to get into, as the errors from not doing so can be hard to catch.

Comment: @DevSolar Personally, I would say that casting when it's not necessary is a very bad habit, since that easily can hide errors. But if you restrict it to the isxxxx family I agree.

Comment: @klutt Yes, I meant it strictly for the is...() / to...() family of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isalpha()` is declared in `ctype.h`

It might be good to know that even though the argument to `isalpha` (and all the `isxxx` family functions) is an `int`, [the behavior is undefined if the argument is negative.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6693878/6699433) So if you're on a machine where `char` is signed as default, you might run into trouble unless you cast first. Like this:

```
char c;
// Some code
if(isalpha((unsigned char) c)) {
```

It can be a good habit to always cast for these functions. However, do NOT use casting as a goto for silencing warnings. It can easily hide errors. In most cases when a cast is needed, your code is wrong in some other way. [Rant about casting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62563330/6699433)

Another pitfall with these functions (and many other C functions that returns an `int` as a Boolean) is that they are required to return zero on false, but are allowed to return any non-zero value on true. So a check like this is complete nonsense:

```
if( isalpha(c) == 1 )
```

Instead do any of these:

```
if( isalpha(c) != 0 )   // If not zero
if( isalpha(c) )        // Use directly as Boolean (recommended)
if( !! isalpha(c) == 1) // Double negation turns non zero to 1
```