# How can I fix the scanf to take data into the array?

Tags: c, scanf

Can someone please advise regarding the scanf?
"message" is an array of 4 rows by 16 columns.
After the user enters the numbers (all 1 digit integers), when hitting "Enter" there is an error message. As said - probably something with the scanf.

```
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            scanf("%d", message[i][j]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Use scanf("%d", &message[i][j]);

Comment: This is the first rule of `scanf` — you virtually always need that `&`.

Comment: `scanf` is simultaneously the most superficially useful, and the most difficult to actually use, function in all of C.  If you're trying to learn how to use `scanf` by trial and error, based on what seems reasonable, you are going to fail, and badly.  Please read some documentation on it first!

Comment: First off, **never** use `scanf()` without checking the return code....

Answer (score 7):

`scanf` *seems* like a nice, simple, easy, convenient way to read input.  And in some ways it is, but it turns out that using it correctly can be surprisingly difficult, and it's chock-full of pitfalls.

You're probably not going to want to learn about all of `scanf`'s intricacies at first.  So for now, here are some guidelines for using a *subset* of `scanf`'s functionality, safely.  (For reasons I fail to understand, everybody tells beginners to use `scanf`, but nobody ever teaches rules like these along with it.)

1. Remember to always use `&` in front of the variables you're trying to read.  (This is a special rule, for `scanf` only.  Don't try to use that `&` on the variables you pass to `printf`, for example.)
2. Exception to rule 1: Do *not* use the `&` when you are reading strings with `%s`.
3. If you are reading strings using `%s`, make sure the variable you read into is either a character array that's big enough for what the user is likely to type, or a pointer to `malloc`'ed memory that's big enough for what the user is likely to type.  (See also note below about avoiding overflow.)
4. Be aware that `%s` reads strings that *don't* contain space characters.  You can't use `%s` to read strings (like full names) that might contain spaces.  (For now, please don't worry about how you might read a string that might contain spaces.  See also rule 14.)
5. Don't try to use `scanf` and `fgets` (or the obsolete `gets`) together in the same program.
6. Don't try to use `scanf` and `getchar` together in the same program.
7. Try to limit yourself to only the format specifiers `%d`, `%s`, `%f`, and `%lf`, to read into variables of type `int`, string (see rule 3), `float`, and `double`, respectively.
8. If you want to read a character into a variable of type `char`, you can use `" %c"`, but the mysterious extra explicit space character there is vital.
9. Use only one `%` sign in the format string, to read one variable.  Don't try to read two or more variables in one `scanf` call.
10. **Always** check `scanf`'s return value.  If it returns 0, or the negative value `EOF`, that means it didn't successfully read anything.  If it returns 1, that means it successfully read one value.  (And if you break rule 9, and try to read multiple values, it'll return the number of values it did successfully read, anywhere between 0 and the number you asked for.)
11. If `scanf` returns 0 or `EOF`, indicating that the user did not type a valid value, just print an error message and exit.  Don't try to write code that asks the user to try again, because the user's wrong input is still sitting on the input stream, and there's no good, simple way to get rid of it. (If you really want to write user-friendly code that re-prompts in case of error, `scanf` is not the right tool for the job.)
12. Never put whitespace after the format string.  That includes the newline character `\n`.  (That is, use `"%d"`, not `"%d "` or `"%d\n"`.)
13. Don't try to use the `%[…]` specifier.
14. If you break rule 13 (perhaps because someone told you that `%[…]` might be a way to read a string containing spaces, or a whole line), do *not* put an `s` after it.  The format is `%[…]`, not `%[…]s`.

These rules may seem restrictive, *but* if you follow these rules, you should be able to simply and easily and reliably get simple inputs into your simple programs, which is the goal here.  `scanf` is otherwise remarkably hard to use, and experience has shown that there are something like 17 different horribly frustrating problems that tend to come up, and trying to solve them is a completely unnecessary distraction from your goal of learning C by writing simple C programs.

When you're reading strings with `%s` or `%[…]`, there's a danger: no matter how big the array or `malloc`'ed buffer you're reading into is, the user might type more than that.  To avoid overflow, you can use a format like `%19s` to explicitly tell `scanf` how many characters it's allowed to read. (And remember to subtract 1, to leave room for the terminating `'\0'`.  That is, you'd use `%19s` to read into `char str[20];` or `char *p = malloc(20);`.)

These rules are somewhat numerous. For a simpler set of rules, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69213541/having-difficulty-correctly-inputting-multiple-integers-at-the-same-time-using-s/69223945#69223945).  Putting rules 7, 8, 9, 12, and 13 together, there are really only five complete format strings you want to use with `scanf`: `"%d"`, `"%s"`, `"%f"`, `"%lf"`, or `" %c"`.  (But no commas, no fixed strings, no whitespace other than the explicit space in `" %c"`, nothing else.) Exception: as mentioned above, it's fine to use something like `%19s` to limit the length of a string being read.

If you need to do something more complicated, that you can't do while staying within these rules, it's time to either:

1. Learn enough about [how `scanf` really works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68952584/how-does-scanf-know-if-it-should-scan-a-new-value/68952778#68952778) (and doesn't work) so that you can try to do the thing you want, but without getting stuck on one of those 17 problems, or
2. Learn how to do input using [better and more powerful methods than `scanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537), perhaps by reading whole lines using `fgets` and then parsing them.

Comment: #4 applies to `%[...` also.

Comment: 1. and 2. are over-simplifying to the point of being wrong. They are good guidelines, until you learn what these 3 functions do. After that, mixing them is no problem.

Comment: @hyde They are good guidelines because by the time you learn enough about these functions to be able to mix them, you've learned that `scanf` is more trouble than it's worth, and there'll be no issue with mixing because you won't be using `scanf` at all.

Comment: @SteveSummit It'd be better to tell things how they are: `scanf` will always leave the remainder of the line unread, so if you use `fgets` after `scanf`, read and discard the remainder of the current input line first.

Comment: @hyde That's why option 1 at the end says you can "learn enough about how scanf works so that you can try to do the thing you want".  But to my way of thinking, having to write code to read and discard the remainder of each line, every time you want to use `fgets` after `scanf`, completely demolishes the alleged ease and simplicity of calling `scanf` in the first place.

Comment: The rules do seem quite restrictive, especially #7.  But upon consideration, I agree that they serve their expressed purpose well for people who have not internalized all the gory details of how `scanf` works. Which includes substantially all the C newbies trying to use `scanf` to write simple programs.

Comment: A very good summary, which I have upvoted and benchmarked so I can reference the whole shebang instead of repeating my "favorite" mantra (#8...) for basically every question that includes `scanf()`. Perhaps consider adding chux's advice about limiting the string size with `%s` to avoid overflows. May you reap the upvotes that you deserve!

Comment: @JohnBollinger: More than one conversion specifier gets ugly because then you're in the realm of "one whitespace matches *any kind and number* of whitespaces", "input string must match format string", and the fact that you will be unable to tell, even when checking the return value of `scanf()`, *where exactly the match failed*. I absolutely agree with Steve here, `scanf()` is a can of worms best left unopened. It's only in the standard to mirror `printf()`; IMHO you should only ever use `fscanf()` (sp!) on *known good* input, and eschew `scanf()` entirely.

Comment: Note for future readers: I have rewritten this answer, and renumbered some of the guidelines.  chux's comment refers to what is now rule 2. hyde's comment about "over-simplifying to the point of being wrong" refers to what are now rules 5 and 6.  John Bollinger's comment about "quite restrictive, especially" refers to what's now rule 9.

Comment: @chux Notes about field widths added.

Comment: @Steve Summit: is the space before "%c" really mysterious? Doesn't it simply skip any sequence of spaces? What if I want to read spaces too?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a "&" before "message[i][j]".

```
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {

        scanf("%d", &message[i][j]);
    }
}
```