# how to use gets() function in dynamic memory allocation with structure in c

Tags: c, struct, scanf, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data
{
    char name[100];
    int age;
};

int main()
{
    struct data *p;
    int i, n;
    printf("\nENTER THE SIZE OF STRUCTURE:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    p = (struct data *)calloc(n, sizeof(struct data));

    if (n < 0 || p == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nSTUCTURE DOESNOT CREATED");
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("\nENTER THE INFO FOR %d STRUCTER", i + 1);
            printf("\nENTER THE NAME:");
            gets((p + i)->name);

            printf("\nENTER THE AGE:");
            scanf("%d", &(p + i)->age);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("\n");
            printf("\n%d\t\t%s\t\t%d", i + 1, (p + i)->name, (p + i)->age);
        }
        free(p);
    }
}
```

can I use `gets()` function to store string in this above code
I know I can store with `scanf()` but it will terminated after white spaces and the reference of this program
https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/structure-dynamic-memory-allocation

Comment: Do not use `gets` at all. This function is deprecated for use with older C standard revisions and is completely removed from the newer ones. You can use `fgets` though.

Comment: *"how to use gets()"* - Simple: [you *don't*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used); *ever*. Use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead. First read how it works, then understand how it's different than `gets`, then adapt accordingly.

Comment: so what will we solution with fgets()

Comment: For starters - don't mix it with `scanf`.

Comment: Read the [secret rules about using `scanf` successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72178518/how-can-i-fix-the-scanf-to-take-data-into-the-array/72178652#72178652) that no one ever teaches.

Answer (score 2):

> *how to use `gets()` function?*

Do not use `gets()` for anything. This function is obsolete and cannot be used safely.  Instead of `gets((p + i)->name)`, you can write:

```
scanf(" %99[^\n]", p[i].name);
```

Note the initial space in the `scanf` format string: it tells `scanf()` to skip initial white space, which is necessary to consume the pending newline into the `name` field.  Without this space, `scanf("%99[^\n]", p[i].name);` would fail and return 0 because no characters from `stdin` would match the conversion specification before the newline.

Comment: thanks for solution but their is any way we can use fgets()

Comment: Mixing `fgets()` and `scanf()` is tricky because `scanf()` typically leaves the newline pending in `stdin` and `fgets()` will read an empty line if called immediately after.

Comment: @AyushTalesara It's barely possible to mix `fgets` and `scanf` in the same program, but it's at least twice as hard and twice as confusing as just using `fgets` everywhere, or using `scanf` everywhere.

Comment: @Darth-CodeX: the space is necessary to consume the pending newline left by the previous call to `scanf()`. Answer amended with an appropriate explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Never use [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) function it is obsolete.

Try using `fgets()`

```c
fgets(p[i].name, sizeof(p[i].name), stdin);
p[i].name[strcspn(p[i].name, "\n")] = 0;
```

Comment: Use `sizeof(p[i].name)` instead of `99`, which will also avoid the off-by-one error.  You can safely specify the exact size of the array to `fgets()`.

Comment: This does not work because `scanf("%d",...)` left a pending newline in `stdin` that will be read by `fgets()` as an empty line. Mixing `scanf()` and `fgets()` is tricky indeed.