# I can't figure out why I'm getting a weird output for this

Tags: c, scanf

I am very new to programming and it seems like I've hit a wall with this code I was experimenting with. I'd appreciate it if someone could explain why this comes out weird and what I should do to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, _a, b, _b, c, _c, d;
    
    printf("Enter 1 pair of numbers\n");
    
    scanf ( "%d ,%d", &a, &_a );
    
    printf("Enter another pair of numbers\n ");
    
    scanf ( "%d ,%d", &b, &_b );
    
            c = a + b;
           _c = _a + _b;
            d = c + _c;
    
    printf( "The sum of first numbers in each pair is %d\n", c);
    
    printf( "The sum of second numbers in each pair is %d\n", _c);
    
    printf( "the sum of all the numbers is %d\n", d);

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, the output is like this:

```
Enter 1 pair of numbers
3
4
Enter another pair of numbers
 5
The sum of first numbers in each pair is 7
The sum of second numbers in each pair is -785649472
the sum of all the numbers is -785649465
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: You can infer that a and b were input correctly, but not _a or _b.

Comment: Tip: always check the return value from `scanf`!  In your case, if it doesn't return 2, this means it didn't successfully read both numbers.

Comment: Tip 2: Don't try to read two numbers at a time using `scanf`, anyway — it causes too many problems.

Comment: Tips 3-15: Read these [other secret unwritten guidelines for avoiding `scanf`'s many problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72178518#72178652).

Answer (score 2):

Your `scanf()` function expects to find an input formatted as `number , number`, so if you input it like `number newline number`, it doesn't assign the second value and you get that "strange" value.

To read the values as you're writing them, you should do something like this:

```c
scanf ( "%d %d", &a, &_a );
```

Answer (score 2):

`scanf ( "%d ,%d", &a, &_a );` tells `scanf` to scan for and discard spaces (including other “white space” characters like tab or new-line), then scan for a decimal integer, then scan for and discard spaces, then scan for a comma, then scan for a decimal integer (which may include leading spaces). The input you show does not contain a comma, so the scan for a comma fails when it sees the digit “4” instead. At that point, `scanf` stops. It does not continue scanning and does not store any value in `&_a`. It returns one to indicate that only one item was assigned. However, your program does not check the return value.

When `scanf ( "%d ,%d", &b, &_b );` is executed, the “4” is still in the input stream, unprocessed. So `scanf` scans that and assigns it to `b`. Thus `a` has been set to three and `b` has been set to four, and this is why the output for “The sum of the first numbers in each pair” is “7”. Then the space in `"%d ,%d"` tells `scanf` to scan for and discard spaces, and the comma tells `scanf` to scan for a comma. Again, that fails, and `scanf` stops and returns one, which your program ignores.

At that point, `_a` and `_b` have not been assigned values. Per the C standard, they have no fixed values, and the program is permitted to use any representable number each time they are used in an expression.

To scan input that does not contain commas, remove the comma from the format strings. You also do not need spaces, because `%d` includes scanning and discarding leading white space. You can merely use `scanf("%d%d", &a, &_a);`.

However, also check the return value of `scanf`. You can use:

```
int result = scanf("%d%d", &a, &_a);
if (result != 2)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, expected two input numbers, but scanf returned %d.\n", result);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Add `#include <stdlib.h>` to your program to get a declaration of `exit` and a definition of `EXIT_FAILURE`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a comma in the format strings

```
scanf ( "%d ,%d", &a, &_a );
scanf ( "%d ,%d", &b, &_b );
```

If you are not going to enter it then remove it from the format strings as for example

```
scanf ( "%d %d", &a, &_a );
scanf ( "%d %d", &b, &_b );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `,` to separate `%d`, because of this when you hit enter it also considers that as input too, you can just do it like this it will tell the `scanf()` that all your input will be given formate.

```
   int a, _a, b, _b, c, _c, d;
    
    printf("Enter 1 pair of numbers\n");
    
    scanf ( "%d%d", &a, &_a );
    
    printf("Enter another pair of numbers\n");
    
    scanf ( "%d%d", &b, &_b );
    
            c = a + b;
           _c = _a + _b;
            d = c + _c;
    
    printf( "The sum of first numbers in each pair is %d\n", c);
    
    printf( "The sum of second numbers in each pair is %d\n", _c);
    
    printf( "the sum of all the numbers is %d\n", d);

    return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

A `scanf` format specifier can be composed from three separate kinds of elements:

1. `%`-specifiers.  Things like `%s` and `%f` and `%s` cause `scanf` to (attempt to) parse a value and assign it to one of your variables.
2. Whitespace.  Whitespace in a format string causes `scanf` to skip and ignore whitespace.  But the whitespace in the format string doesn't have to exactly match the whitespace that is entered — as far as `scanf` is concerned, all whitespace is whitespace, and that includes newlines.
3. Literal characters, which are basically anything that's not whitespace or a `%`-specifier.  Literal characters in the format string mean that `scanf` must see those same characters in the input, exactly.

Also, most (though not quite all) format specifiers automatically skip leading whitespace all by themselves.

Your problem was that you had a literal character (a comma) in your format string, and this caused `scanf` to look for that character in the input, and fail when it wasn't found.

Since it's always possible for `scanf` to fail and not parse the values you expected — and therefore not fill in your variables with anything — it's highly recommended to always check `scanf's return value.  For your program that might look like this:

```
printf("Enter 1 pair of numbers\n");

if(scanf("%d ,%d", &a, &_a) != 2) {
    printf("input error!\n");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Enter another pair of numbers\n");

if(scanf("%d ,%d", &b, &_b != 2) {
    printf("input error!\n");
    exit(1);
}
```