# Why does C skip scanf()

Tags: c, scanf

So I was writing a quick program to get information about a patient from a hospital and it keeps skipping the scanf() at a certain point (at around line 34) and moves on to the scanf() after it. Here's the part that keeps bothering the life out of me:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<windows.h>

int main(void){
    char choice_1, choice_2, *blood_group, *spec_conditions, *allergies;
    printf("Enter the patient's medical details.\n\n");
    printf("Enter your blood group: ");
    scanf("%s",&blood_group);
    printf("Does the patient have any allergies:(y/n)");
    scanf("%c",&choice_2);
    if (choice_2 == 'y'){
        printf("Kindly enter the allergies: ");
        scanf("%s",&allergies);
    }else{
        allergies = "No allergies";
    }
    printf("\nDoes the patient have any special conditions:(y/n)");
    scanf("%c",&choice_1);
     if (choice_1 == 'y'){
        printf("Kindly enter the condtion: ");
        scanf("%s",&spec_conditions);
    }else{
        spec_conditions = "No special conditions";
    }
    printf("Displaying details...\n");
    sleep(2);
    system("cls");
    printf("\t\t\tPATIENT DETAILS\n");
    sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate.  Your `%c` reads the newline left behind by `%s`.  The fix is to use `” %c”` to skip white space.

Comment: Your scanf pretend to store on unitialized pointers.

Comment: See these [guidelines for calling `scanf` simply and safely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72178518#72178652).

Comment: In your question, you are referring to line 34. However, your posted code only has 32 lines and therefore does not have a line 34. Please [edit] your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem 1:**

```
char *blood_group, *spec_conditions, *allergies;
```

```
scanf("%s",&blood_group);
```

```
scanf("%s",&allergies);
```

```
scanf("%s",&spec_conditions);
```

What this does is it attempts to write a string of an unknown length to the address of `char *` variables, resulting in a 'buffer' overflow if the string is larger than a pointer, or a wild pointer that points to a random location.

Do not pass the address of the pointer to `scanf`, pass the pointer itself. Furthermore, the pointer must point to writable memory. This can be done by declaring it as an array.

**Problem 2:**

`scanf("%c")` reads the newline left when the user hits enter to read the string and moves on. Use `scanf(" %c")` instead to skip leading whitespace and read the actual character.

**Try:**

```
int main(void){
    char choice_1, choice_2, blood_group[256], spec_conditions[256], allergies[256];
    printf("Enter the patient's medical details.\n\n");
    printf("Enter your blood group: ");
    scanf("%255s",blood_group);
    printf("Does the patient have any allergies:(y/n)");
    scanf(" %c",&choice_2);
    if (choice_2 == 'y'){
        printf("Kindly enter the allergies: ");
        scanf("%255s",allergies);
    }else{
        strcpy(allergies, "No allergies");
    }
    printf("\nDoes the patient have any special conditions:(y/n)");
    scanf(" %c",&choice_1);
     if (choice_1 == 'y'){
        printf("Kindly enter the condtion: ");
        scanf("%255s",spec_conditions);
    }else{
        strcpy(spec_conditions, "No special conditions");
    }
    printf("Displaying details...\n");
    sleep(2);
    system("cls");
    printf("\t\t\tPATIENT DETAILS\n");
    sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```