# C Macro to generate arbitrary length scanf/printf format

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Normally you would write a `scanf` function call like below:

```c
scanf("%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3);
```

I would like to have a macro function that goes something like this:

```c
#define REP_FORMAT(X) "%d " * X

// Usage:
scanf(REP_FORMAT(3), &num1, &num2, &num3);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Honestly this is why `for` loops exist. Just `scanf()` N times.

Comment: Tip: Instead of a sequence of variables, use an *array* of the same type.

Comment: Related: [How can I fix `scanf` to take data into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72178652/60281) (And, seriously, *do* read that answer, it's full of good advice.)

Answer (score 1):

This type of bounded repetition is not possible using the C-standard preprocessor alone for an arbitrary number of repetitions.

However for a given maximum number of repetitions you can get something that probably meets your needs with code like:

```c
#define REP_FORMAT_0 ""
#define REP_FORMAT_1 "%d"
#define REP_FORMAT_2 "%d " REP_FORMAT_1
#define REP_FORMAT_3 "%d " REP_FORMAT_2
#define REP_FORMAT_4 "%d " REP_FORMAT_3
#define REP_FORMAT_5 "%d " REP_FORMAT_4
#define REP_FORMAT_6 "%d " REP_FORMAT_5
#define REP_FORMAT_7 "%d " REP_FORMAT_6
#define REP_FORMAT_8 "%d " REP_FORMAT_7
#define REP_FORMAT(x) REP_FORMAT_##x
```

This code assumes your argument to `REP_FORMAT` is a literal non-negative integer less than 9 (as shown in the question), and not an expression or variable.

Comment: Identifiers starting with `_` and an upper case letter are reserved. We can't use them. https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html

Comment: @kamicuk you are technically correct, although this almost never causes a problem in practice. Nevertheless I've edited the answer to address your concern.