# Scanf reading an entire string when I told her to only read the first character

Tags: c, while-loop, char, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    while(1){

        char a;
        scanf("%1c",&a);
        getchar();
        if (a=='a'){
            printf("It is a.");
        }

    }
    
}
```

I told scanf: "Read the first character of whatever the user gives you", and she said "yes master", but if I input the string "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" i get the output:

It is a.It is a.It is a.It is a.It is a.It is a.It is a.It is a.It is a.It is a.It is a.It is a.It is a.It is a.

Doesn't the %1c mean it throws away the rest of the string? As a bonus point, after I get that long output, I keep inputing a and it does nothing. What in the god damn is wrong with this cursed command?

Comment: No, `%1c` does not mean to throw away the rest of the string.

Comment: Don't try to use `scanf` to read individual characters.  That's not what it's for.  Use it to easily read single integers, or single floating-point numbers, or maybe simple strings (not containing whitespace).  Anything else tends to be more trouble than it's worth.  See also [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72178518#72178652).

Answer (score 0):

In this while loop when a sequence of characters like this `"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"` is typed

```
while(1){

    char a;
    scanf("%1c",&a);
    getchar();
    if (a=='a'){
        printf("It is a.");
    }

}
```

in the first iteration of the loop the first call of `scanf` reads the first character `'a'` of the entered string. Then the call of `getchar` skips the second character `'a'` of the entered string and then in the next iteration of the loop the first call of `scanf` reads the third character `'a'` of the entered string and so on.

That is the input buffer still keeps the entered string until it will be entirely read.

It seems what you need is the following

```
while(1){
    char a;
    scanf(" %c",&a);
    while ( getchar() != '\n' );
    if (a=='a'){
        printf("It is a.");
    }
}
```