# Using fscanf to get a string and a number

Tags: c, scanf

I am using fscanf to get a name and a number from a file in this format and print it out:

```
   Jim: 100.00
  John: 200.00
  Adam: 300.00
Miguel: 400.00
```

My output is not being printed properly.

I've tried using `while(fscanf(filep, "%s %lf", name, balance) != EOF)` but it always seems to print in this format:

```
   Jim:: 0.0000
  John:: 0.0000
  Adam:: 0.0000
Miguel:: 0.0000
```

It seems that it reads the name correctly, but it adds the colon at the end of the name
(I have a colon in the printf, so I would like to avoid the extra colon)
but it doesn't read the numbers correctly.
I'm not really sure what I can do to fix this, so help would be appreciated.

Comment: `while(fscanf(filep, "%s %lf", name, balance) != EOF)` is insufficient.  Post a [mcve].

Comment: `fscanf()` is including the colon in the string. If you're getting a double colon, it's because you're adding another one in the `printf()`. Don't do that.

Comment: Remember, `%s` uses whitespace as the delimiter of the string. So the `:` is part of the name.

Comment: As it looks like this is your first time using `scanf`, you might want to read [these guidelines for using it safely and correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72178518#72178652).  (Your problem is rule #1 on that list.)

Comment: *it reads the name correctly, but it adds the colon at the end of the name*, no, it read a string just like you asked it to.  *You* added the "extra" colon, in your `printf` call. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some indications to fix your program:

- to read the name before the `:`, you can use `%[^:]`
- to avoid a potential buffer overflow, you should specify the maximum number of characters to store into the destination array:

  ```
  char name[30];
  scanf("%29[^:]", name);
  ```
- to skip the pending newline and potential initial whitespace, add a space at the start of the format string:

  ```
  char name[30];
  scanf(" %29[^:]", name);
  ```
- to consume the `:`, just add a `:` after the conversion format.
- to parse the number, use the `%lf` conversion if `balance` has type `double`, but pass the address of the variable with the `&`:

  ```
  char name[30];
  double balance;
  scanf(" %29[^:]: %lf", name, &balance);
  ```
- why not use `&` for `name` you might ask... because `name` is an array: passing an array as an argument to a function implicitly passes a pointer to its first element.  You could do this explicitly as `&name[0]` but it is simpler and idiomatic to just pass `name`.
- you should check that the conversions succeeded: `scanf()` returns the number of successful conversions, hence it will return `2` if the input was parsed correctly.
- your output shows `Miguel:: 0.0000` because the `:` was read as part of the name with `%s` and the balance was printed with a `%.4f` format.  The first problem is solved thanks to the `%29[^:]` conversion, for the second you should use `%.2f` to output 2 decimals.
- To make it easier to detect the end of file and recover from invalid input, it is recommended to read one line at a time with `fgets()` and use `sscanf()` to attempt to convert the contents of the line.

Here is a function to parse the file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int read_file(FILE *fp) {
    char line[200];
    char name[30];
    double balance;
    int count = 0;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
        if (sscanf(line, " %29[^:]: %lf", name, &balance) == 2) {
            count++;
            printf("%s: %.2f\n", name, balance);
        } else {
            printf("invalid input: %s\n", line);
        }
    }
    return count; // return the number of lines converted
}
```

Note that this method will accept and ignore extra contents after the balance on the line.  To detect and report this problem, you can use the `%n` conversion to retrieve the number of characters read and report the problem if the line has extra non whitespace contents:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int read_file(FILE *fp) {
    char line[200];
    int count = 0;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
        char name[30];
        double balance;
        int len = 0;

        if (sscanf(line, " %29[^:]: %lf %n", name, &balance, &len) == 2) {
            count++;
            printf("%s: %.2f\n", name, balance);
            if (line[len] != '\0') {
                printf("extra characters: %s\n", line + len);
            }
        } else {
            printf("invalid input: %s\n", line);
        }
    }
    return count; // return the number of lines converted
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the posted code isn't complete (the variable definition is missing) we can't know for sure but

```
while(fscanf(filep, "%s %lf", name, balance) != EOF)
```

is wrong for a number of reasons.

1. Checking for EOF is insufficient
2. `balance` is (most likely) a `double` but `%lf` requires a `double pointer`
3. `%s` may lead to buffer overflow. Always use a width specifier for `%s`

Something like:

```
char name[100];
double balance;
... open file, etc ...

while(1)
{
    int res = fscanf(filep, "%99s %lf", name, &balance);
    if (res == 2)
    {
        // Fine - print values
    }
    else if (res == EOF)
    {
        // Done
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        // Error: Didn't read 2 values
        // Add error handling...
    }
}
```

That said, I'll recommend using `fgets` followed by `sscanf` for better control .

Notice that use of `%99s` will result in `:` being part of name. You can add code to remove it (if needed). Also take a look at the answer from Barmar [https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780112/4386427`It](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780112/4386427%60It) has an alternative to `%99s` that may be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `scanf()` format string so the `:` is not included in the name being read:

```
scanf(" %[^:]: %lf", name, &balance)
```

The space at the beginning is needed to skip over the initial whitespace. And you need `&` before `balance`.

Comment: Er, shouldn’t that have a width in there somewhere (to prevent buffer overflow)? Also, you forgot a `%`.

Comment: @Barmar I added a `%` before `[^:]` as I'm sure it was just a typo. I didn't add a width specifier as that would be too many changes.