# Can somebody explain to me this line of code from the give post "printf("extra characters: %s\n", line + len);"

Tags: c, printf

[Please see the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75780094/using-fscanf-to-get-a-string-and-a-number)

Given the below data in the file:

```
Jim: 100.00 Amed

John: 200.00
```

```
if (line[len] != '\0') {                    
    printf("extra characters: %s\n", line + len);
}
```

the first invalid line will be:

```
Jim: 100.00 Amed
```

and the len 12 and the output will be:

```
extra characters: Amed
```

How does `line + len` give:

```
Amed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line + len` will increment `line`'s value (a memory address) by the size of its underlying data type.

So if `line` originally was:

```
Jim: 100.00 Amed
```

`line + 12` would evaluate to:

```
Amed
```

See also: [Pointer Arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394767/20017547) and [c-faq.com section 4](http://www.c-faq.com/)