# C langauge, char filename[] = scanf("%s", filename); Causing error

Tags: arrays, c, scanf

I am wondering why Vscode is throwing an error at the line:

```c
char filename[] = scanf("%s", filename);
```

The error says:

[image: Error]

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of characters read, that is an `int` not a `char*`

Comment: You seem to have skipped some very important early parts of your beginners learning material.

Comment: @rioV8 `scanf` returns the number of *conversions* successfully performed.

Comment: @rioV8 Why are you telling *me* this? You have misrepresented what [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns, I am simply correcting you.

Comment: @Oka It was more a remark to the OP: Why is the OP asking us what he can find himself in the C reference

Comment: *"I am wondering why Vscode is throwing an error at the line:"* - Because that line is not even remotely correct.   You cannot put gibberish in, and expect it to work.  That code is not based on any valid C syntax.

Comment: @Hemalurgical_Potato For starters: *First*, you need to declare your array `char filename[50];`, *then* you can try to read in to it using `scanf("%49s", filename);`.

Comment: @abelenky You are too harsh.  It's almost perfectly valid C syntax.  It's wildly far from what we (that is, we who already know C) know is the way to do it, but it's kinda hard to explain what's *actually* wrong with it!

Comment: @Hemalurgical_Potato Arrays and strings are special in C.  If you were dealing with, say, simple numbers, you could write `float sqrt2 = sqrt(2.0);` on one line and it would work just fine.  But you can't initialize an array (that is, something like `char filename[]`) using a function call, because functions never return arrays.

Comment: Since this is your first time calling `scanf`, you might want to read [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72178518#72178652) for using `scanf` safely.  (It is a *very* strange and troublesome function.)

Comment: @abelenky "You cannot put gibberish in, and expect it to work." Please remember that there are newbies too, they might not know about the functions and stuff in C. Being rude isn't a solution.

Answer (score 2):

For starters to use the function `scanf` you need to include header `<stdio.h>` and the compiler reminds you about this

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

The return type of the function `scanf` is `int`. The function is declared like

```
int scanf(const char * restrict format, ...);
```

and the function returns

> 3 The scanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input
> failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed.
> Otherwise, the scanf function returns the number of input items
> assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the
> event of an early matching failure.

So this declaration

```
char filename[] = scanf("%s", filename);
```

does not make sense.

You need to declare a character array with a fixed number of elements and after that to call the function `scanf` as for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

//...

char filename[20];
scanf("%19s", filename);
```